# Get ROLE of a user not logged in TWIG Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to know how can i know if a user is granted when it's not the current user in twig.

I use this code for the current user:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
    <a href="...">Delete</a>
{% endif %}
```

But i would like to be able to do the same thing with ohter users that are not logged in at the moment.
Thank you.

**Edit:**
In fact i think there isn't a direct way with twig to test role of a user that is not authenticated.
So i did it directly in the twig template, test if a user is admin or not, then set var.
(in my question i was searching how to do in a list of users.)

```
{% set from_user_is_admin = false %}
{% for role in from_user.getRoles() %} 
    {% if role == 'ROLE_ADMIN' %}{% set from_user_admin = true %}{% endif %}
    {% if role == 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' %}{% set from_user_admin = true %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if from_user_admin == false %}THIS USER IS NOT ADMIN{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it would be much easier if you implemented an isGranted function in the User entity:

```
Class User implements UserInterface {
    ...
    public function isGranted($role)
    {
        return in_array($role, $this->getRoles());
    }
}
```

You can now easily check for granted roles in every layer of your application. 
In PHP:

```
$user->isGranted("USER_ADMIN")
```

Or in Twig:

```
user.granted("USER_ADMIN")
```

If you need to check a role for the current user, you can do this in Twig:

```
app.user.granted("USER_ADMIN")
```

Note: the variable "app" is globally defined.

Note 2: this code may throw an exception if you use it outside the secured area of your app, since app.user would be NULL.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I did after several months of symfony2 learning.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24323223/877323 if you wanto to handle role inheritance and not only 'strict' role

Answer (score 7):

You can use similar statement to the above with "not" :

```
{% if not is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
    <a href="...">Delete</a>
{% endif %}
```

or use else statement:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
    <a href="...">Delete</a>
{% else %}
    {# something else for guest user, not logged in #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yes i know that funtion, but is_granted is testing the current user. The thing i would like to know is doing the same thing form a user object that is not the current user. I edit my question to put the way i did it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You should create either a twig [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html), or a twig function.

Creating a [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) is very simple, using your code:

```
{% macro admin_status(from_user) %}
  {% set from_user_is_admin = false %}
  {% for role in from_user.getRoles() %} 
      {% if role == 'ROLE_ADMIN' %}{% set from_user_admin = true %}{% endif %}
      {% if role == 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' %}{% set from_user_admin = true %}{% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% if from_user_admin == false %}THIS USER IS NOT ADMIN{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

You can then use it in the same file as `{% _self.admin_status(user) %}`. You may also move it to a separate file, and use twig's [import](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/import.html) tag to gain access to it.

Creating a twig function is a better option, for details see [extending twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html). It boils down to creating a regular function, that may be called from twig, so code like this becomes possible:

```
{% if user_is_admin(user) %}
```

You'll also need to read [enabling custom twig extensions](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/dic_tags.html#enabling-custom-twig-extensions).

Comment: WOw, Thank you very much, I can put that code in a twig template, include it, then reuse the code !

Answer (score 1):

i did it this way, have this snippet in the global twig file, in my case layout.html.twig

```
{% set is_admin = false %}
{% if app.security.token.user.roles is iterable %}
    {% for role in app.security.token.user.roles %}
        {% if role == 'ROLE_ADMIN' or role == 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'  %}
            {% set is_admin = true %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

then i can use anywhere

```
{% if is_admin %}....{% endif %}
```