# Update roles in security.context without need to logging in again

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I use FOSUserBundle in my project. I have a Controller `AcmeArticleBundle:Edit` which has a route prefix `/editor`. And in my security.yml I added an access control.

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/editor/, role: ROLE_EDITOR }
```

Now I add `ROLE_EDITOR` to a user in a controller. But user cannot access `AcmeArticleBundle:Edit` and security context does not change until logging out and logging in again.

Comment: If you want to avoid logging out and back in, you have to manually update the session's token with the new role see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084054/symfony-2-1-7-update-security-token-setting-specific-roles-after-the-user-is-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I had to make a new security token and set it as security context.

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$user->addRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
$this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->updateUser($user);
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can update the roles manually:

```
// YourController.php
$roles = $this->getToken()->getUser()->getRoles();
$roles[] = 'ROLE_NEW';
$this->getToken()->getUser()->setRoles($roles);
// Then persist your user entity or the new role will be lost at the next page call
```

(Code for `Symfony2.0` but it should not be very different in `2.4`)

Comment: My problem is that the action which adds the role to this user is not ran by the same user.

Comment: The roles are reloaded at every request, so if you persist the user entity it should work.