# Symfony Security access control doesn't react to user changes in DB

Tags: symfony, security, session, entity, access-control

My user provider is set to User entity.

The entity has getRoles() model and it works properly.

My problem is that:

- There are two user roles in the website (**Admin** and **Regular**)
- Regular user can't access Object creation (**access_control** is set that only Admins can do this)
- User logs in while he is still has '**Regular**' role
- I go and edit this '**Regular**' user in DB and set it to 'Admin'
- User is still logged-in, the access_control still treats him as '**Regular**'
- **$this->getUser()->getRoles()** has the '**Admin**' role.
- User still can't access the Object creation route, because access_control assumes he is still '**Regular**'
- He has to re-login, and only then the **access_control** lets him access the Object creation route.

***How do I do so that that database changes apply to the session, without having to log out?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with Symfony's voters: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

Could not be able to achieve it without Security Roles without logging-out.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625137/update-roles-in-security-context-without-need-to-logging-in-again) is similar to yours. The accepted answer was:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$user->addRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
$this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->updateUser($user);
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

Comment: Hey, yeah, it seems that i need to persist the change through code, not through database. By the way, I've read that I can incorporate complex access controls with expressions, so I'll read more about it.