# Check specific user permission in a twig view

Tags: php, symfony

In a TWIG view of my Symfony 5 project, I have the following piece of code :

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Created at</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for user in users %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.createdAt|date('d/m/Y H:i') }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Nothing impressive. I wanted to know if there was a way to check if the `user` in my loop has a specific role, let's say `ROLE_STAFF` (More precisely, I want to check it against the hierarchy. If he has a role that "inherits" `ROLE_STAFF`, it should also satisfy the condition). I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078270/check-if-a-role-is-granted-for-a-specific-user-in-symfony2-acl/24078528#24078528) but it's quite old, and I'm hoping maybe something has been implemented since the moment it was written.

I tried injecting the `AccessDecisionManagerInterface` in my `User` entity without any good result. My method (thereafter) does not work because `$this->decisionManager` is null. I guess it has not been injected properly. I inject it by the constructor :

```
public function __construct(AccessDecisionManagerInterface $decisionManager)
{
    $this->decisionManager = $decisionManager;
}

public function hasRolePermissions(string $role)
{
    $decisionManager = new AccessDecisionManager();
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($this, '', '', $this->getRoles());
    return $this->decisionManager->decide($token, [$role]);
}
```

Although a solution that does not use `isGranted`, like a service, or an injection, is perfectly acceptable to me, I would prefer to keep it simple. I was planning to build a twig function, but I would like to know if I'm reinventing the wheel or not. This seems a common enough issue, so I hope there is some built-in functionality I'm not aware of.

Comment: If it's a simple check, not involving authorization and you don't have role inheritance going on, why don't you just check against the role array in `user.roles`?

Comment: The problem is that it involves hierarchy. If a user has the ROLE_ADMIN (which inherits from ROLE_STAFF) but not the ROLE_STAFF then I can't find him this way.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the marked question. I wish to check the permissions of a user **which is not the current user** against the role hierarchy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get ROLE of a user not logged in TWIG Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080530/get-role-of-a-user-not-logged-in-twig-symfony2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`RoleHierarchy`](https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/master/Role/RoleHierarchy.php) class to find all "reachable" roles for a current user.

In the Symfony framework, this class is available as the `security.role_hierarchy` service (autowirable as `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchyInterface`).

```php
// check for ROLE_STAFF while taking the role hierarchy into account
$isStaff = in_array(
    'ROLE_STAFF',
    $roleHierarchy->getReachableRoles($user->getRoles())
);
```

You can write [a custom Twig extension (e.g. a custom Twig test)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension) to be able to do this in your templates.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I had it right, I'll have to write my TWIG extension then. I wonder why it's not included in the framework, it seems pretty basic.

Comment: Caveat : the name of the method in `RoleHierarchyInterface` is `getReachableRoleNames` as of Symfony 5.0.7 and not `getReachableRoles`